# How to link WSL to my already installed python on windows?

Tags: python, python3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, recently I installed the WSL from the Windows Store and now I'm having some problems with python.
I already have python and some of its libraries installed on my Windows 10, but whenever I type `py` in the Ubuntu terminal it doesn't understand it, it only understands when I type "python3". Is there a way to add the `py` command to activate python?
Also in the interactive mode (`$python3 -i`), whenever I try to `import` any library (i.e numpy) it throws an error (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`) while I already have numpy installed on my Windows.
It's like the WSL is acting like it can't even see python and its libraries installed in my windows!

[an image of my WSL struggling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fTBZ.jpg)

Answer (score 9):

As explained in [Windows Subsystem for Linux interoperability with Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop), there are some conditions that need to be satisfied in order to execute Windows programs from the WSL command line:

> ## Run Windows tools from WSL
>
> WSL can invoke Windows binaries directly from the WSL command line
> using [binary name].exe. For example, notepad.exe. To make Windows
> executables easier to run, Windows path is included in the Linux $PATH
> in Fall Creators Update.

*Some irrelevant stuff omitted*

> Windows binaries must include the file extension, match the file case,
> and be executable. Non-executables including batch scripts. CMD native
> commands like dir can be run with cmd.exe /C command.

So, if your Windows version of python3 is a regular executable, you should be able to run it as

```
python3.exe
```

Otherwise (apparently this includes the version of python3 installed to WindowsApps from the Microsoft store) you will need to use

```
cmd.exe /C python3.exe
```

Comment: Also keep in mind that Windows python is going to behave differently than WSL python, so you *might* just want to install Python3 within WSL.

Comment: so if i installed python 3 using WSL, will there be a conflict with the already installed python? I mean if i installed it, it would be like installing python in a whole different machine, and hence i will install the libraries. right?

Comment: @YoussefHeshamAlsoly as far as I know that's correct - however that's really up to Microsoft

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try it ASAP and hopefully won't mess up anything

Comment: A [snip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snip) is an obscure term for anyone not being a native English speaker, so [edited](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1160722/revisions) and upvoted!  **;-)** Drop by in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) sometime...  **0:-)**

Answer (score 1):

So here's the problem. WSL has a different version of python installed, as opposed to your windows machine. You can link them like this:

Run these commands in WSL:

```
$ sudo apt remove python3 python3-pip
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

Now in your `.bashrc` on WSL, add the following:

```
alias python3="cmd.exe /C python3"
alias pip3="cmd.exe /C pip3"
```

Now restart your WSL application, and there! It should work! This worked for me very well...