# Open a file from the console with a windows program ubunto subsystem

Tags: windows-10, libraries, windows-subsystem-for-linux, 20.04

I have installed ubuntu subsystem in windows 10, and right now i creating a file with the command:
touch file.foam
and after that with the explorer in windows i open the file with a program.exe, is it possible from the command line to say creat the file and also open it directly?

Comment: Possibly related: [How to link WSL to my already installed python on windows?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160722/178692)

Answer (score 0):

You can launch windows programs from wsl, try

```
touch test.txt
notepad.exe test.txt
```

Comment: hi, I am getting several errors, of missing libraries? here is a image of the errors i am getting https://ibb.co/rQsydyz

Comment: pls send "echo $PATH" output

Comment: hello, here you have a copy of exho $PATH https://docs.google.com/document/d/154F_WhbDw7uL7QeGWlQW5LY4H_LJsooobBRY2rq3rzo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What command are you trying to run - make sure the DLLs are somewhere on $PATH.